# Use multiple names in a Sonarqube Measure (filter)

Tags: sonarqube

I want to create a filter that has multiple developers in one filter so I can show teams of people at a time instead of one developer or all developers.

Is this possible?  We are using developer cockpit to get developer stats.

Comment: As your question relates to a SonarSource commercial plugin, would be better to ask it to supportATsonarsource.com. But the short answer is no while waiting for http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/VIEWS-121.

Comment: I am geting a demo of Views and Dev Cockpit next week.  Thanks for the suggestion.